# javascript map function accepting multiple array as arguments

Tags: javascript

How would a js function like this be written?

```
map(add, [1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12])
 => [15, 18, 21, 24]
```

I'm trying to write a native js version of the clojure `map` function

```
(map + [1 2 3] [4 5 6])
=> [5 7 9]
```

where map accepts a function and any arbitrary number of arrays after that

Comment: With JavaScript code. Explain what you actually want, and what you've tried.

Comment: Are you asking how to write a varargs function in JavaScript?

Comment: `Array#reduce` may be best here. Something like `[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]].reduce(function(a,b) {return b.map(function(_,i) {return (a[i]||0)+b[i];});},[]);` should do it.

Comment: That's not `map`, but `zipWith sum` what you are looking for

Comment: @Bergi... its definitely `map` in clojure =)

Comment: What output is this meant to generate..?

Comment: This is the 5th legitimate question in a row that I've asked that has been downvoted or voted to close. I'm really sick of this type of unwarranted behaviour for actual legitimate questions. Please don't assume that ANY question you don't understand the meaning of is worthless. Ask, comment, find out whats going on and THEN downvote. This type of wreckless behaviour is ruining my experience of SO and I'm sure I am not the only one thats becoming increasing frustrated with the site.

Comment: @zcaudate: just like in the real life, not all people are so smart as you, but they would rather <s>kill</s> downvote you than admit that. Be cool.

Comment: @thg435: thanks =). I needed that vent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
pythonic_map = function(fun) {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1)
    return args[0].map(function(_, i) {
        return fun.apply(null, args.map(function(x) { return x[i] }));
    });
}
```

Example:

```
function add(a, b, c) {
    return a + b + c
}

z = pythonic_map(add, [1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12])
console.log(z) // [15,18,21,24]
```

This uses the length of the first argument, to use the shortest/longest argument:

```
pythonic_map = function(fun) {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return args.reduce(function(m, x) {
        return (x.length < m.length) ? x : m; // or > for the longest
    }).map(function(_, i) {
        return fun.apply(null, args.map(function(x) { return x[i] }));
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised the idea of `map`ping a multi-argument function over multiple arrays is so foreign to Javascript.